# Why am I not able to access the jar file in my gradle project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, compilation

I have a springboot project that uses gradle. I am trying to add an external jar file locally and access it within the application. I have done the following:

1. Created `app/libs` folder and placed my `external-jar.jar` file in it.
2. In my `build.gradle` file I have added this line: `implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`

I am unable to access the classes of the external jar in my application. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any input would help, thanks!

Java: 11
Springboot: 2.7.9
IDE: Intellij
Gradle: 6.8

Comment: `app/libs` is not the same as `libs`. Where is your `build.gradle` relative to the `app` directory?

Comment: @JoachimSauer It is present in the same hierarchy as the ```build.gradle``` file

Comment: I tried to change the `build.gradle` to `implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'app/libs')` and I am able to access the `external-jar.jar` when I try to edit the code, but the compilation fails with the `ClassNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the `app/libs` directory as a [Gradle repository](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:flat_dir_resolver):

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'app/libs'
    }
}
```

Then declare the dependency like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation name: 'external-jar'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is working for me in IntelliJ IDE.

Please create the folder as libs inside app and put the jar.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: The sense of using a `flatDir` repository - which **is** much better than using `files` or `fileTree` - is to then **not** use `files` or `fileTree` or the `flatDir` repository is simply not used. Besides that you should not wrap it inside `maven { ... }`, that is just visual clutter. The other answer has the correct syntax.